# How to get Certificate used in Identity Provider in openam

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, openam, opensso

We are service provider and support SAML based single signon. We want our customers to register us as Service provider in their OpenAm.

When they register us as remote SP, they need to provide us the Signing certificate. How can they easily get certificate so that they can provide us?

In OpenAm when we choose to register Google Apps / SalesForce, at one steps it gives option to download certificate which will be uploaded in Google Apps / SalesForce. But While Registering remote SP, it does not give any certificate.

So is there a way to get certificate easily while registering remote SP similar to Google Apps / SalesForce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is that your customer provides you with SAML meta data. This is a standard format for sharing information about your SAML setup. This also contains the public key for the private key they use to sign.

SAML metadata can be exported from OpenAM. This can be done by the use of export metadata page.
Have your customer go to the following URL

`https://<IdP_HOST>/openam/saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp?entityid=IDP_ENTITY_ID`

From there the metadata can be exported to XML.

Comment: It it our own custom Java application running on Jetty server. Not using any service provider. We have generated SP's metadata file with certificated and registered that SP with xml file in OpenAm as remote SP. But data posted to our SP after authentication is signed by another certificate which is associated with IdP on OpenAm server. We are not signing and sending response to IdP but we are getting signed response from IdP after authentication.

Comment: Ok, so you want the certificate they are using to sign? Or is this another question

Comment: Yes, I want the certificate they are using to sign. Alternative can be that I provide them certificate which they should use to sign. For 2nd case I generated SP metadata and uploaded in OpenAm to register SP, but still it is using some other certificate. So for now its fine to just get certificate they are using to sign.

Comment: I see I dont think you can provide the private key they should sign with in the metadata. What you should do is to get the meta data from your customers OpenAM. This can be done by use of exportmetadata page. https://<IdP_HOST>/openam/saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp?entityid=IDP_ENTITY_ID.

This metadata will contain the certificate they are using to sign

Comment: I got the point. But what are the certificate in SP metada file meant for? Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Typically the SP sends the IDP the public key of the certificate that the SP uses to sign.

Comment: Lets continue in discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29317/discussion-between-hridayesh-and-stefan